# What's the best approach to use Collect tracking code pageviews as conditions on Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, analytics

Documentation on Marketing Cloud is a bit scarce for this use case.

We want to shoot emails for users who visited a certain page on our website but don't have a certain property/attribute on their Profile/DataExtension.

Is it possible? How can it be done?

Was thinking on: Collect -> Attribute Group/DataExtension -> Data Relationship -> Journey Builder. But this is a path quite filled with unknowns.

Comment: Hope I've answered your question Andr3, if so - would you be so kind as mark as best answer? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the question you ask about "Conditions" is Entry Conditions, and for this I do not believe that this is possible out-of-the-box. There may however be a couple of ways to achieve what you are trying to do, I'll iterate through a few of the solutions:

**1) Raw Data Feed Integration**
You can get the collect data stored in AWS, populated in a data extension which you could then either use journey builder email audience to evaluate against it, or use automation audience if you need to run some queries first.

**2) Audience Builder**
I believe web collect data can be captured in audience builder, and you could then publish these audiences for journeys. Note, however, that audience builder at present - to my knowledge - has a 24h delay to data (it's updated daily)

**3) API Calls**
You can use an API call to inject people directly into a journey based on e.g. a page view, and then - depending on your data model and MC attributes available, you can do a second API call to update the row, if things change or you can use solution #1 (or maybe #2) as decision splits within the journey

**4)Engage Support / Professional Services**
If your use case is aligned with an abandoned browse or cart feature, there might be a PS agreement you can enter, who can help you with this.

**5)Leverage a third party tool**
I was shown a demo yesterday by www.getstride.com, and they seem to address this particular use case, i mean EXACTLY this use case, but it comes at an added cost. Seems really cool though. It's developed by some of the guys from the PI team.

Hope this helps